# what is process of deploying easygui application?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, easygui

can we deploy 'easygui' application? 
If so, how? 
I have done a simple easy GUI application using Python 3.6 
Now I want to create a setup file for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a nice explanation from zadacka, when I contacted him on Github. A standard way to deploy is [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html). There are a lot of ways of doing the deployment. Within the python world, setuptools is the successor to distutils, and the wheel packaging system is the successor to the egg.

For converting a .py file to a .exe

You can use any of the below 3 tools.
They have their own website with nice documentation.

1. [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)
2. [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/)
3. [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org)

these are used to generate a .exe file.

We need tools like Windows Installation wizard / Microsoft Installation wizard.
The one which was most suggested is [Inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) it is also a free tool.